# Android How to set multiple gravity values programmatically in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

In Java it was like:

```
layoutParams.setGravity(Gravity.END|Gravity.BOTTOM);
```

How to do this in Kotlin?

Comment: Just copy it into your IDE and it will ask you if it should convert it to kotlin. Or use the "Convert from Java" Feature at try.kotlinlang.org

Answer (score 81, accepted):

This operator is called "bitwise or" and it has analogue in Kotlin. Use it like this:

```
layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.END or Gravity.BOTTOM
```

Comment: The operator is normally used in infix syntax. Edited your answer to reflect that.